# How to fail in the compilation time instead of runtime exception

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have this simple code

```
def doStuff(x: Int) = {
 ...
}
```

However, this method will not support if x is less than or equal to 0, so I am using require

```
def doStuff(x: Int) = {
   require(x > 0, "x should be greater than 0")
}

doStuff(0) // runtime exception
```

but this is happening in the runtime exception, how can I change it to use Implicit to show the error in the compilation time ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly is `x` coming from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This definitely isn't possible in the general case—the compiler just doesn't have enough information about an arbitrary `Int`. You do have a couple of options, though. If you're willing to require the argument to be a literal, you can use a macro:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros, scala.reflect.macros.Context

def doStuffImpl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._

  x.tree match {
    case Literal(Constant(xLit: Int)) if xLit > 0 => c.literalUnit
    case Literal(Constant(xLit: Int)) =>
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "x must be > 0")
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "x must be a literal")
  }
}

def doStuff(x: Int) = macro doStuffImpl
```

And then:

```
scala> doStuff(1)

scala> doStuff(0)
<console>:12: error: x must be > 0
              doStuff(0)
                     ^

scala> val y = 1
y: Int = 1

scala> doStuff(y)
<console>:13: error: x must be a literal
              doStuff(y)
                     ^
```

It's also possible to use something like [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s type-level natural numbers:

```
import shapeless._, nat._, ops.nat.{ Diff, LT }

def doStuff(n: Nat)(implicit lt: LT[_0, n.N]) = ()
```

And now you can do more complex stuff like this:

```
def doStuffWithDiff[C <: Nat](a: Nat, b: Nat)(implicit
  sum: Diff.Aux[a.N, b.N, C],
  lt: LT[_0, C]
) = doStuff(Witness.witnessN[C].value)
```

And now `doStuffWithDiff(10, 10)` and `doStuffWithDiff(10, 11)` won't compile, but `doStuffWithDiff(10, 9)` will.

This is a kind of [dependently typed programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), and it can be very powerful, but trying to do it in Scala (which is only a dependently typed programming language if you squint really hard at it) does introduce a fair amount of syntactic overhead, so you probably want to use this approach only in cases where compile-time correctness has a very high value.

Answer (score 0):

The most common alternative is to define a simple wrapper class PositiveInt (or whatever name is most adequate) which makes the runtime check. Your function will always have exactly what it expects...